# PHP PayPal REST API: display item descriptions if applicable

Tags: php, paypal-rest-sdk

I have below create payment with paypal script, I wanted some of the items variations to be able set to `setDescription();` if any,

Currently all items will show same description (variations) with below script:

```
foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $key => $cart_itm) {

    $keys = array_keys($cart_itm);
    $matches = preg_grep('~^p_alt\-variation\-\d+~i', $keys);
    //show variations if any
    if(count($matches) > 1) {
        foreach($matches as $matched_key) {
            $variations[] = $cart_itm[$matched_key];
        }
    }

    $subtotal = $cart_itm['p_price'] * $cart_itm['p_qty'];

    $item[$key] = new Item();
    $item[$key]->setName($cart_itm['p_name'])
            ->setCurrency(PAYPAL_CURRENCY)
            ->setQuantity($cart_itm['p_qty'])
            ->setDescription(implode(' / ', $variations))
            ->setPrice($cart_itm['p_price']);

    $items[] = $item[$key];
    $customData[] = $cart_itm['p_id'].':'.$cart_itm['p_qty'];

}
```

print_r($_SESSION['products']);

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [p_name] => Motorbike Helmet G88
                [p_code] => 2102649
                [p_coverImg] => 12-1466446199-wI5qx.png
                [p_id] => 12
                [p_price] => 68.00
                [p_alt-variation-1] => Blue
                [p_alt-variation-2] => XL
                [p_qty] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [p_name] => Digital PH Meter
                [p_code] => 14171613
                [p_coverImg] => 4-1460428321-I1pNy.jpg
                [p_id] => 4
                [p_price] => 31.00
                [p_qty] => 2
            )

    )
```

How to pass items variations to `->setDescription()` if available?